# The second most

Tags: word-usage

> - I like her the most

I know this is okay, but how about these?

> - I like her the second most
> - I like her the third most
> - I like her the least
> - I like her the second least

Are they ok?

If not, why?

If yes, how come I don't see them on Google?

Comment: Google is not a linguist. It is a recording mechanism. It records things from stuff found online. It is not a grammarian or English checker.

Answer (score 1):

They are all OK. They're not very typical, simply because it's not common to rank people or things beyond the most/least or "second most"/"second least".

As far as why you're not seeing them in Google results, it might be because you're searching for them as individual words, rather than as a phrase. Try using quotation marks:

- ["second most"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22second%20most%22)
- ["third most"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22third%20most%22)
- ["second least"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22second%20least%22)
- ["fifth least"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22fifth%20least%22)  (just to prove the concept)

Answer (score 0):

These sentences are just fine, besides the fact they are missing a period. You can't expect to find every single sentence on Google.
I like her the third most means out of a certain number of people, you enjoy her less than 3 of the people, but more than the rest. I like her the least. Least just means out of everyone else, you don't like her more than anyone.

Next time trying use a **dictionary** to break down the **individual parts**.

Answer (score 0):

There is a list of people.

I like her the most. [of those five people]
I like her the least. [of those five people]

Of all the people on the list, I like her second most.

Usually, we don't go beyond second. She ranks third as the person I like most or least. She comes in third position as the person I like most or least.